# Stash + Matrix Parse Order?

Tags: matrix, stash

The following code works **if** I comment out the Matrix fields (images `{stash:st_{pre_channel}_image_url}`).

However, I can't get the code working with the image tags back in. I'm guessing it's a parse order issues :-/

I've tried everything I can think of, but no joy. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

```
  {preload_replace:pre_channel="people"}

    {exp:channel:entries disable="" channel="{pre_channel}" dynamic="no"}
    {categories}
        {exp:stash:append_list name="{pre_channel}_{category_id}" parse_tags="yes"}

        {!-- Main  --}
        {stash:st_{pre_channel}_title}{title}{/stash:st_{pre_channel}_title}
        {stash:st_{pre_channel}_page_url}{page_url}{/stash:st_{pre_channel}_page_url}

        {!-- Content --}
        {stash:st_{pre_channel}_intro}{cf_{pre_channel}_intro}{/stash:st_{pre_channel}_intro}
        {stash:st_{pre_channel}_maincontent}{cf_{pre_channel}_maincontent}{/stash:st_{pre_channel}_maincontent}

        {!-- Page Specific --}
        {stash:st_{pre_channel}_location}{cf_{pre_channel}_location}{/stash:st_{pre_channel}_location}

        {!-- Image --}
        {stash:st_{pre_channel}_image_url}
            {cf_{pre_channel}_images limit="1"}
                {mx_image}
            {/cf_{pre_channel}_images}
        {/stash:st_{pre_channel}_image_url}

        {stash:st_{pre_channel}_image_caption}    {cf_{pre_channel}_images limit="1"}{mx_caption}{/cf_{pre_channel}_images}{/stash:st_{pre_channel}_image_caption}

    {/exp:stash:append_list}
    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Get

```
    {exp:channel:categories channel="{pre_channel}" style="linear" show_empty="no"}
        <div class="span12">
        <h3>{category_name}</h3>
        <div class="row">
            {exp:stash:get_list name="{pre_channel}_{category_id}"}
                <article class="span4">
                    <a href="{st_{pre_channel}_page_url}">
                        <img src="{st_people_image_url}" alt="{st_{pre_channel}_title}">
                    </a>
                    <header>
                        <a href="{st_{pre_channel}_page_url}"><h2>{st_{pre_channel}_title}</h2></a>
                        <p class="meta">{st_{pre_channel}_location}</p>
                    </header>
                </article>
            {/exp:stash:get_list}
        </div>
    </div>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is the matrix inside {categories} variable pair? Looks like the point is that.

Matrix tag pairs won't get parsed if they are inside the categories tag pair.

I tried to find a way to do what you need, but I couldn't find any solution without using multiple channel:entries, on one way or another. Even using addons, we can't scape of this. Per example, there are some plugins that group entries by its categories, as [Category Sorted Entries](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/category-sorted-entries) and [NSM Categories](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-categories), but they don't allow you the get data from matrix fields, which means: multiple channel:entries variable pairs!

So, lets try to do this without addons.

```
{preload_replace:pre_channel="people"}
{exp:channel:categories channel="{pre_channel}" style="linear" show_empty="no" parse="inward"}
    <div class="span12">
    <h3>{category_name}</h3>
    <div class="row">
        {exp:channel:entries disable="" channel="{pre_channel}" dynamic="no" category="{category_id}"}
            <article class="span4">
                <a href="{page_url}">
                    <img src="{cf_{pre_channel}_images limit='1'}{mx_image}{/cf_{pre_channel}_images}" alt="{title}">
                </a>
                <header>
                    <a href="{page_url}"><h2>{title}</h2></a>
                    <p class="meta">{cf_{pre_channel}_location}</p>
                </header>
            </article>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </div>
</div>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

By this way, the channel:categories variable pair will created one channel:entries variable pair for every category. Entries could repeat if they have more than one category on this group.

Sadly, this is a really heavy code to parse. You should enable some cache feature on the tags or on the page.

Comment: The Matrix loops through a set of images. Surely it needs to be inside the {categories} tags to be associated to the exp:stash:get_list?

Comment: Matrix tag pairs won't get parsed if they are inside the categories tag pair. I'm not sure I understand why you need a unique stash list for each category? Isn't the list data you are capturing the same regardless of category?

Comment: Yes, the list data is the same, but I'm grouping the entries by category. Is this not the way to go? I started off using this example - http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/7518#25397

Comment: @MatthewEllis, I see. I gonna take a better look and return to you.

Comment: Thanks Robson, I think that's set me in the right direction... will have a play and get back to you! :)